# В чем разница между «при том что» и «притом что»?

Tags: орфография, союзы

Скажите, пожалуйста, *в чем разница между **«при том что»** и **«притом что»**?*

Вопрос тупой, но для меня он актуален. Дело в том, что я никак не могу перестать думать над этим вопросом. В учебниках старых такого я найти не смог. А новых у меня нету. Не маленький уже.

Answer (score 8):

Правильно не можете найти, нетути такого в учебниках.

Есть союз "при том что" (с запятой перед или внутри) и не существует союза "притом что".

[***ПРИ ТОМ(,) ЧТО, союз***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_780)

> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «при том(,) что»,
>   выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может целиком
>   входить в придаточную часть (и не разделяться запятой), но может и
>   расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза,
>   перед словом «что»).
>
> *Их семейной жизни не хватало тепла, доверия, при том что Анна действительно отдаст за детей и мужа всю кровь до капли.* Ю. Нагибин,
>   Терпение. *Сразу же выяснилось, что Куренков отделался легче – удар
>   пришелся в плечо, при том что рукой он более или менее свободно
>   двигал*. В. Маканин, Антилидер. *Это еще при том, что мы всем
>   поголовно «отмазки» платим – и кухонному шефу, и кладовщикам, и
>   старшему бармену, и директору ресторана.* В. Кунин, Кыся. *Но,
>   пожалуй, слишком уж серьезно к себе относится – это при том, что
>   неутомимая хохотушка. В. Шукшин, Шире шаг, маэстро!*

@ В «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН рекомендуется написание «притом что» (слитное).

А зачем нам рекомендации? У нас у самих револьверы найдутся.

> **Вопрос № 228978**
>
> Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, в каких случаях пишется "притом
>   что", а в каких "при том, что". И какой будет пунктуация? Спасибо.
>   Юлия
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза *при том что*,
>   выделяются с двух сторон знаками препинания. При этом первый знак
>   препинания может ставиться либо перед составным союзом, либо между его
>   частями. В «Русском орфографическом словаре РАН» рекомендуется
>   написание *притом что* (слитное), хотя в остальных словарях,
>   справочниках и художественных текстах пишется раздельно: *при том
>   что*.

P. S. Нашла такое новенькое, [никаким учебником не отображённое](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=204149). Хотя и аргументированное, как правило:

> _ Притом что_ - сложный союз, употребляется в значении "хотя, несмотря на то что". Правильно слитное написание, оно кодифицировано
>   «Русским орфографическим словарем РАН» под ред. В. В. Лопатина и рядом
>   других источников.

Пример употребления:

> Притом что из всего множества российских банков только 35 продают паи
>   ПИФов, становится очевидно, что основное развитие банковских сетей
>   продаж еще впереди.

Comment: Подумать не могла прежде, что могут возникнуть споры вокруг такого вопроса) Мне лично с написанием "притом что" смириться тяжело - даже несмотря на ссылку на «Русский орфографический словарь РАН». Может, какие-то смысловые, дискурсивные, интонационные отличия между этими двумя написаниями есть? Конструкция со слитным написанием представляется более цельной и устойчивой.

Comment: А мне наоборот, более естественным видится раздельное написание (вне случаев отдельного "притом"). Смысловое различие здесь явное, но вряд ли стоит его выражать модификацией написания: на устной речи это не отражается, а противоположность смыслов и без того определяется позицией относительно основного высказывания (в начале - выражает противопоставление, а в конце - подтверждающее дополнение).

Answer (score 6):

Нет здесь ничего  неоднозначного, кроме того,что всё запутали электронные словари, вернее их клоны, в правильных словарях всё правильно. О союзе "притом что" спорили на многих сайтах, приводили в пример Орфографический словарь РАН, но я его в глаза не видела, а вот про Лопатина - точно ложь,у него союз ПРИТОМ, а не "притом что":

притом, союз (`он работает и притом учится), но местоим. при том (при всём при том)
Лопатин. Словарь русского языка Лопатина. 2012 [ПРИТОМ | slovar.cc](https://slovar.cc/rus/lopatin/1055960.html)

Значит, если уступительное или местоимённо-определительное значение, в роли союза местоимение с предлогом (при том,что), если присоединительное - союз притом = к тому же, да и .

1. Этот режиссер знаменит, при том (ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВЕ), что его фильмы почти никто не видел.
2. При том (УСЛОВИИ), что на кафедру хореографии поступали самые одаренные, воз и ныне там.
3. Расходы одного из участников уменьшены, при том (РЕШЕНИИ), что другой участник полностью освобождается от бремени.

В академической грамматике:"§ 3055. Уступительные отношения, оформляемые союзами дифференцирующего типа, могут выступать во взаимодействии с другими семантическими компонентами, участие которых предопределяет ослабление или утрату собственно-уступительного значения. Соответственно выделяются конструкции с отношениями собственно-уступительными, обобщенно-уступительными и альтернативно-уступительными.

Собственно-уступительные отношения оформляются союзами несмотря на то что, невзирая на то что (офиц.), даром что (устар. и прост.), независимо от того что, ПРИ ТОМ ЧТО, при всем том что, вопреки тому что. Все эти союзы имеют аналитическую структуру: в их составе выделяется семантический центр, который, в противоположность семантически нейтральной части (что), выполняет квалифицирующую функцию. Большинство этих союзов образовано на базе непервообразных предлогов, в своем лексическом значении заключающих уступительный элемент. В отличие от причинных союзов аналогичной структуры (см. § 3031, 3041), расчленение уступительных союзов не сопровождается позиционным разобщением их компонентов."

Всё, никаких ПРИТОМ ЧТО здесь нет, поищите сами. А в Нацкорпусе грамотность проверять некорректно, только примеры употребления.

Answer (score 4):

Есть союз "притом". В сочетании с последующим "что" он крайне редок и скорее всего потребует запятой (Он работает притом(,) что учится). Убедительных примеров я не нашла. Напротив, в приведенном примере очень хочется написать раздельно и с запятой.

Поэтому, думаю, вариант слитного использования "притом что" скорее всего надо отнести к некорректным вопреки встречающемуся написанию.

Comment: Примеры из Нацкорпуса (434 примера)  для союза ПРИТОМ ЧТО http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F0%E8%F2%EE%EC+%F7%F2%EE+

Comment: Там запятая перед "что". Это два союза получаются.

Answer (score 2):

**Вопрос сложный и неоднозначный, поэтому вряд ли возможно остановиться на одной форме написания.**

В некоторых случаях ПРИТОМ ЧТО ― это явно присоединительный союз, причем его изъяснительная часть может выражать разные значения (соответствие или несоответствие ранее названной ситуации). В других случаях его  сложно назвать присоединительным союзом, например:

(1) **При том что** правящая лейбористская партия обладает большинством в парламенте, принять соответствующий закон не составило бы труда (= так как).

(2) **При том, что** я очень уважаю NN, я люблю его как человека пишущего, как человека талантливого, яркого, неоднозначного. [Татьяна Соломатина. Мой одесский язык (2011)]. Это изъяснительный (вмещающий) тип придаточного.

(3) **И это при том**, что я себя причисляю к счастливейшим людям. [И. Л. Аренс, Л. Е. Аренс. Письма Н. Н. Пунину (1940)]. И это **при том что** цена нефти на мировых рынках падает, как и стоимость рубля . Предложение должно начинаться с присоединительного союза, тогда "**и это все притом что**"  ― такое составное союзное выражение?

(4) В свое время Петра Первого ругали за то, что он, присоединив кучу иноземцев, заставляет теперь русский люд защищать их от врагов ― **притом что** те неблагодарны и презирают русских. [Вера Краснова, Павел Кузенков. Романовы: империя верных // «Эксперт», 2014]. Там тоже много ресурсов тяжелой нефти, **притом что** это гораздо более освоенный и пригодный для жизни регион, чем Восточная Сибирь и Арктика. Это действительно союз ПРИТОМ ЧТО, можно заменить синонимом К ТОМУ ЖЕ.