# Запятая после ПРИТОМ

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Это, действительно, сложная задача, поскольку исследователь вынужден попутно определиться с тем, что он видит в качестве субъекта всего исторического процесса, притом(,) что эта проблематика совершенно не входит в круг его задач.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках? И почему?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427465/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это действительно сложная задача, поскольку исследователь вынужден попутно определиться с тем, что он видит в качестве субъекта всего исторического процесса, **притом что** эта проблематика совершенно не входит в круг его задач.

Итак, ***притом что***. Этот составной союз писался по-разному, а также мог расчленяться  или нет. Но сейчас наконец навели порядок: **союз не расчленяем запятой и пишем слитно.**

**Лирическое отступление**

**Правильное решение?** Мне лично нравится, вот только надо бы объяснить выбор, а это оказалось нелегко.

Любимый учебник по современному синтаксису, и тот не помог. Меня интересовал хотя бы вид  сложного предложения — это ССП, СПП, БСП?  Но такого союза в книге не было.

Тогда придется не списывать, а думать. **ПРИТОМ** — **сочинительный** присоединительный союз, а падежные формы местоимения **ЧТО** (что, для чего, с чем и т.д.) — это **подчинительные** союзные слова. Если их соединить, то получится ...**сочинительный союз изъяснительного типа**. Ну а как его еще назвать?

**Немного статистики из Нацкорпуса**

**Раздельное написание** ПРИ ТОМ ЧТО:  1536 примеров, но обычно не позднее 2004 года.

**Слитное написание** ПРИТОМ ЧТО:  450 примеров.

**Наличие запятой**: расчленение союза встречается довольно часто и в современных текстах.

**Примеры**

**1) С запятой**

Одним словом, объедение, да и только. **Притом, что** пища необыкновенно легкая.  [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

Глайдеров на борту у него имелось даже два, и это **притом, что** жилые отсеки комплектовались также на двоих. [Владимир Васильев. Шуруп (2013)]

**2) Без запятой**

Здесь важен пример Японии, которая восприняла основные западные ценности после Второй мировой войны, и это обеспечило ей впечатляющее экономическое развитие, **притом что** японцы остались самими собой, сохранив язык, народные традиции. [Евгений Ясин, // «Знание - сила», 2010]

Как вы на это решились, **притом что** успех не был гарантирован? [«Русский репортер», № 37 (215), 22 сентября 2011, 2011]

Comment: В каких источниках **до** пресловутой рекомендации словаря РАН, союз "притом" начали рассматривать как "часть составного"? "Притом" (в обоснованно слитном написании) и "что" никогда (кроме как по недоразумению) не встречаются.

Comment: **P.S.** А не встречаются они по той причине, что "притом" всегда ссылается на _предшествующее_ высказывание (вся Дания - тюрьма, притом образцовая), сочетание же "_при том (обстоятельстве)/, /что_" буквальным образом ссылается местоимением "то" на далее раскрываемое обстоятельство. Столь же буквальный смысл имеют составляющие многострадального выражения  "в том числе", которое волею публичных журналистов стало превращаться в подобие "составного местоимения" или междометия. Последствием здесь стали уже не просто странности правописания, а повальные речевые ошибки.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю. "Русский орфографический словарь" РАН рекомендует слитное написание, всё остальное лирика. Речевые ошибки - понятие неточное и часто субъективно понимаемое, а словарь - дело серьезное.  Это закон, который нельзя нарушать, его приняли не журналисты, а профессиональные лингвисты. Наверное, они взвесили все за и против.

Comment: Пример 1993 года: Нил перекрывают пороги (катаракты) и делят его на автономии, недоступные одна для другой: вода течет та же, а люди в автономиях самые разные ― черные, коричневые, белые, с разными обычаями и религиями, с разной историей, ПРИТОМ ЧТО для всех племен и народов это священная река, божество, которое создало государства и культуры. [Сергей Залыгин. Экологический роман // «Новый мир», 1993]  Хорошие писатели и без РАН писали правильно (слитно и без запятой).

Comment: Законы языка (в их пользу говорит приводимая вами статистика публикаций) "старше" административных распоряжений РАН.

Comment: Так это исполнители - им как РАН скажет, так они и будут писать. А я говорю о настоящих писателях, которые интуитивно чувствуют правильность русской грамматики. Вопрос сложный, задайте его на форуме, что-нибудь вроде "Как обосновать слитное написание союза ПРИТОМ?".

Comment: Любопытно, как настоящие писатели разглядели бы новоявленный союз (с явно присоединительной частью) в _начале_ предложения с точно таким же смыслом: _При том, что соответствующая проблематика совершенно не входит в круг задач исследователя, он вынужден попутно определиться с тем, что он видит в качестве субъекта всего исторического процесса, и потому это действительно сложная задача._

Comment: Присоединительные конструкции часто встречаются в начале предложения, они там замечательно себя чувствуют.  ПРИ ТОМ,  ЧТО - это присоединительный союз? А Вы правила расчленения союзов знаете? Например: Я приехал для того, чтобы объясниться. - Я приехал,  для того чтобы объясниться. Видите, что здесь одна запятая, а не две? Но здесь варианты,  так как этот союз зависит от логического ударения, а вот присоединительному союзу зачем это логическое членение, которое и прочитать-то невозможно. Вот это понимают и   чувствуют  люди, которые относятся к языку с настоящей, а не формальной  любовью.

Comment: Я с самого начала говорю не о запятых, а о допустимости с некоторых пор пристраивания к слитно пишущемуся союзу "притом" последующего "что" и объявлении всего вместе составным союзом. "Ненастоящие" писатели (страница из справочника к ЕГЭ) не без оснований продолжают приводить устаревшую _норму_, без особого энтузиазма ссылаясь в сноске на рекомендацию лопатинского словаря:
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=St8m39-T4CUC&pg=PA119&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U1bwNb2EZQSgKxKAHILWL2m9KYPow&w=1280

Answer (score 3):

Приведу ответ на вопрос с Грамота.ру:

**Вопрос № 251203**

> ```
> Здравствуйте!
> Какова разница между предлогами "притом что" и "при том что"?
> Спасибо!
> ```
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> ```
> Это один и тот же союз. "Русский орфографический словарь РАН" 
> рекомендует только слитное написание: притом что.
> ```

Для знающих русский язык не первый день звучит довольно непривычно. Но на Грамоте много вопросов по этому союзу и все их ответы в пользу слитного написания. В школьных (и не только школьных) учебниках теперь тоже так учат.

Запятая после "притом" не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Это ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО сложная задача, поскольку исследователь вынужден попутно определиться с тем, что он видит в качестве субъекта всего исторического процесса, ПРИ ТОМ ЧТО эта проблематика совершенно не входит в круг его задач.

Comment: А что, это неправильный ответ?